# Insertar datos de una tabla MySQL en otra MySQL que tienen distintos campos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Veamos, tengo dos tablas. Una es pedidos_remoto y otra es pedidos. Ambas están en MySQL, en el mismo servidor, y el problema es que pedidos tiene 49 campos, pero pedidos_remoto ahora tiene 50 y podría tener muchos más en el futuro. Un requisito clave para comprender la problemática es que se parte del supuesto de que ambas tablas NO tendrán los mismos campos exactamente, es decir, coincidirán en la mayoría, pero pedidos_remoto tendrá varios campos que no están en pedidos.

El caso es que tengo que hacer una app que detecte qué registros están en pedidos_remoto y no en pedidos, y que luego los inserte en pedidos. Estoy sabiendo qué registros están en pedidos_remoto a partir del campo agregado=0, que significa que NO ha sido agregado a la tabla pedidos.

```
function selectAgregado0MSAccess($conMSAccess){ //TESTEO APROBADO

    echo "<h3>Sácame todos los campos de la tabla de MSAccess dónde agregado=0</h3>";

    $queryMS="SELECT * FROM pedidos_remoto WHERE agregado=0";
    $lecturaMS=mysqli_query($conMSAccess, $queryMS);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($lecturaMS)){
        $datosagregado0MS[]=$row;
    }
    
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump ($datosagregado0MS);
    echo "</pre>";
    
    return $datosagregado0MS;
}
```

Pues bien, luego con el array $datosagregado0MS, quiero meter los datos en la tabla pedidos:

```
function insertarAgregado0MSAccessIntoMySQL($datosagregado0MS, $conWebService){

    
    //Ahora ya procedo a realizar la inserción
    // El nombre de la columna sale de arrayColumns y el del valor del array de datos agrupados

    foreach ($datosagregado0MS as $row) {

        // var_dump($row); die();
        $sql="INSERT INTO pedidos VALUES ('".implode("','",$row)."');";
        if(mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql)){
            echo "Se han insertado los datos correctamente en pedidos";
        } else {
            echo "Error:".$sql."<br>"."No se han insertado los datos de forma correcta";
        }
    }
} //No me hace ningún tipo de inserción porque datosagregados0MS[] resulta que me pilla todos los valores, y que no puedo meter todos los valores en pedidos
```

Básicamente, el tema es... ¿Cómo le digo ahora a mi código que quite el campo "agregado" a la hora de coger todos los datos de la tabla, si precisamente busco los datos por "agregado=0"? ¿Qué lógica puedo implementar para que esto sea sostenible en el tiempo? Porque ahora sólo hay un campo que no coincide, pero en el futuro habrá varios que no coincidan entre ambas tablas. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Dado que tu programa va a hacer un mapeo entre dos tablas, tu código debería usar un mapa que una campo de origen con campo destino. Y luego usar eso para armar el `INSERT` ignorando (por ejemplo) los campos que no estén en el mapa.Y usando la forma `INSERT INTO <table> (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (...)`

Comment: y para la replicación, yo te recomendaría que hagas un store procedure, metas a una tabla temporal lo que tenga agregado = 0, lo insertes a tu tabla pedidos y al final todo lo que este en tu temporal lo actualizas en tu tabla de pedidos pedidos_remoto, con un inner join, para asegurar que solo se actualice lo que se inserto.